# Why are all $3$-cycles conjugate in $A_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am reading Dummit and Foote's proof that $A_5$ is simple, and I saw the statement

$$\text{All twenty 3-cycles are conjugate in $A_5$}$$

However, I tried to conjugate $(123)$ into $(132)$, and I couldn't find an even conjugator. I believe the way to find all conjugators is as follows:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(123) & (123) & (123)\\
(132) & (321) & (213)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
By reading vertically, we see that the possible conjugators are $(23)$, $(13)$, $(12)$, all of which are odd.

I think I must be wrong, there must be other conjugators; but on the other hand I don't see how there could be any others. What is going on here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does (2 3)(4 5) work?

Comment: @MatthewDaly Ohh thank you that is cool!

Comment: 0n that note, $(13)(45)$ and $(12)(45)$ must work too.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yup